# Using Order By with Union - SQL Statement

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have a database with direct messages from one user to another.

---

Table name: dm

id int(11) Primary Key

to: varchar

from: varchar

message: varchar

---

I have a SQL Statement that selects the distinct values from the to and from column as if they were one column. ($username is a session variable)

```
"SELECT DISTINCT from
 FROM dm
 WHERE to = '$username'
 UNION
 SELECT DISTINCT to
 FROM dm
 WHERE from = '$username'
 ";
```

I am checking to see if this user has received or sent any messages basically. I want to ORDER BY id of dm. How can I change my code so I get the same results and it orders by id DESC? If I simply enter ORDER BY like so, I get an error because I didn't select it... Thank you so much for the help

```
"SELECT DISTINCT from
 FROM dm
 WHERE to = '$username'
 UNION
 SELECT DISTINCT to
 FROM dm
 WHERE from = '$username'
 ORDER BY id DESC
 ";
```

Comment: DISTINCT tends you limit your ORDER BY options, for good reason in some senses. If you had 10 "froms" with the same value, but different id values; which id value should the single disintct "from" value be ordered by?

Comment: Sample data and desired results would explain what you really want to do.  The query returns what you want to know without needing an `order by`.

Comment: is it necessary for you to use union?

Comment: Why not have a user id  , like every other DM system ever? And watch out for reserved words

Answer (score -1):

If I got exactly what you wanted to do you should keep things separate:

1st step: your original code, plus the user ID added to the dataset

```
CREATE TABLE new_table_name AS
  SELECT DISTINCT ID, from
  FROM dm
  WHERE to = '$username'
  UNION
  SELECT DISTINCT ID, to
  FROM dm
  WHERE from = '$username';
```

2nd step: order by ID

```
CREATE TABLE ordered_table AS
      SELECT *
      FROM new_table_name 
      ORDER BY ID DESC;
```